# Enable "mysql_clear_password" plugin in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, kerberos, pam

I'm trying to enable our MySQL users to authenticate against our corporate user database via PAM (Kerberos). I can login with my credentials to our MySQL server with command line if I use "--enable-cleartext-plugin" in the command. If I try to login with phpMyAdmin I get the following information:

`#2059 Cannot log in to the MySQL server`

Is there a way to enable such plugin in phpMyAdmin without hacking any PHP files?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

For future reference: I fixed this by adding

> mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_READ_DEFAULT_FILE, '/etc/my.cnf');

in `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/dbi/mysqli.dbi.lib.php`
inside the function `PMA_DBI_real_connect`

With

> [client]
>
> enable-cleartext-plugin

in `/etc/my.cnf`